Calculating reserved amount on Kusama asset hub
I'm looking for a way to calculate the reserved amounts on the Kusama Asset Hub. I've written some code to calculate the reserved amounts for Uniques deposit.
    api.query.uniques.class.entries().then((classes) => {
         const myClasses = classes.filter(([_uniquesId, uniquesInfo]) => String(uniquesInfo.toPrimitive().owner) === formatted)
           .map(([_uniquesId, uniquesInfo]) => uniquesInfo.toPrimitive());
    
         const totalClassesDeposit = myClasses.reduce((acc, myClass) => {
            const depositAsBn = amountToMachine(String(myClass.totalDeposit / (10 ** decimal)), decimal);
    
            return acc.add(depositAsBn);
         }, BN_ZERO);
    })

The code works well for most accounts,  some, like this one,
"FezDtF8FLKPHdVitXXhYhop9yEs2ee4uMjMbgDFtUoMsoAZ"
have additional reserved amounts due to proxy deposits.
The sum of the proxy deposit and Uniques deposit exceeds the reserved amount in balances.
Could someone please help me with this issue?
